# Convert byte array to float in Lua [Float Data Structure]

Tags: floating-point, lua, memcpy

I have the ability to read the memory with Lua, but I've run into a problem.
I want to read a float value.

I have, what I presume to be a float, in the memory which looks like this.

```
Byte Array 65 B6 40 43 EC 35 87 41 51 04 9E 3F
Float Value 192.712478637695
```

I know the float value because I'm using a memory editor.
In Lua I have a function similar to memcpy, it's called readmem(Address,bytes) it returns an integer value.

How would I read the byte array into a float in Lua using readmem.

For the sake of this question I suppose you could assume that the 6 in 65 is address 00000000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weird, this seems to be stored in middle-endian order. (I checked this with http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatApplet/IEEE754.html)

Anyway, you can do the conversion in pure Lua using code from http://yueliang.luaforge.net/

See also http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-03/msg00910.html

If you can use C, try one of the libraries listed in http://lua-users.org/wiki/StructurePacking

Answer (score 3):

This is a fair amount of work to get everything right.
You'll need to extract the exponent and significand (the significand is sometimes called the mantissa), convert to float using `math.frexp`, and then negate the result if the sign bit is set.  You'll also have to recognize denormalized numbers and NaNs.  (In a normalized number, the most significant bit of the significand is implicit; in a denormalized number it's explicit.)
If you simply must do this yourself, you'll find it helpful to read Dave Goldberg's article on everything a computer scientist needs to know about floating point.
Also keep in mind that a Lua number is an IEEE double, and be careful about precision.

If I were doing this myself, there's no way I'd go through all this pain—instead I'd **write C code to read the bytes and call `lua_pushnumber`.**

Answer (score 3):

[`string.pack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.pack) / [`string.unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.unpack)

Passing `'f'` as the first parameter will return a 4 byte string of the single precision representation, while `'d'` will return an 8 byte string of the double precision representation. You can even declare the endianness of the float

Comment: Old comment, but this saved it for me. 

`buffer = {}
value = 3.142342432423
FLOAT_SIZE = 4
-- ensure we are dealting with a float
value =  value + 0.0
  
-- pack the string, 
b = string.pack('f', value)

-- then get the bytes.                
for i = 1, 4, 1 do
    buffer[i] = string.byte(b, i);        
    print (string.format("0x%x", buffer[i] ) )
end
`

Answer (score 0):

You must write a C function to accomplish the conversion. Lua does not have casts or anything like them.

Comment: I'm sure you can accomplish the task without adding a function in C to convert it, although I realize this is the easy way out.  I'm sure if I understood better how a float data structure worked I could form a string and then convert it to a float in Lua.
Since I have the ability to read the memory directly I really don't see what's stopping me from patching together a float.
This is a lazy answer I can't vote it down because my rep isn't high enough.

Comment: @Nowayz: In theory, that is possible. However, in reality, you'd be making many, many assumptions about the data structure of a float. In addition, you could only ever convert it to a number, which is a double, not a float. In addition, your byte array is not a float. A float is 32bit or 4 byte. You have 12 bytes. That's just one example of how wrong what you're trying to do is. If you had the address in C, then you could just perform a pointer cast to get the raw representation, but it would still be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the answer from @lhf a little:

```
function BinToFloat32(bin)
  local sig = bin:byte(3) % 0x80 * 0x10000 + bin:byte(2) * 0x100 + bin:byte(1)
  local exp = bin:byte(4) % 0x80 * 2 + math.floor(bin:byte(3) / 0x80) - 0x7F
  if exp == 0x7F then return 0 end
  return math.ldexp(math.ldexp(sig, -23) + 1, exp) * (bin:byte(4) < 0x80 and 1 or -1)
end
```

I can confirm that this works perfectly for little endian byte input.